# Android webview loading iframe inside html file

Tags: javascript, android, web-applications, webview

Needing some help with this,
i am trying to create a web app in Android Studio but after the last update i got a trouble with the webView widget, the first activity load the html file into the webview, here is ok, but into the html file i need to load web content into the iframe tag, i mean, not in the whole webview, just into the tag but after the last update the iframe is not loading content anymore.

I already put the internet permission tag in the manifest...

This is the main activity.java

```
package tv.tencanal10.tencanal10;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Android Webview");
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

    }
}
```

and this is the index (as an example)

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<p>Dashboard</p>
<iframe src="https://www.google.hn/" width="100%" height="400px"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Right now, the iframe tag just show a blank page, i will be thankfully if someone can help me with this.

Comment: check this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/29463436/6244429